# Spotify Web-Control Desktop Player

Tags: spotify

I wish I could control the current song, pause / play, fast forward or rewind music, all through a social network that I'm developing. To study in depth the spotify, I saw that he already has something like a Webservice that does exactly what I need, but only accepts requests from domain "embed.spotify.com", I believe as a form of protection for handling this information without user authorization,

Question:

Is there is any role in spotify API that allows these functions with user's authorization?